# LNK1127 on lib file generated from .def (for a gfortran dll)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, linker

Linking to a .lib file generated from a .def file triggers LNK1127: library is corrupt

I am doing a custom build of scipy. The current step that fails is when linking a c dll that will depend on a fortran dll compiler with Mingw gfortran.

The exact error line is

> build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Debug\libdqag.I4OTSSA4SIYUTZ6NF6DULDGYRZ5LBVRR.gfortran-win_amd64.lib
>   : fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt

So i assume it's that library among those linked in the command line that is corrupt.

Gfortran generated the fortran .dll, and a .def file

Then lib.exe generated a .lib file from the .def file

But when using that lib file a the final link line, i get the LNK1127.

It doesn't seem i can blame gfortran for the corrupt file since lib.exe generated it. The def file looks valid to me, and lib.exe did not complain. So doesn't dumpbin. The .lib is of the correct output platform (x64). Scipy build script used the x86_64 visual studio tools (x86 binaries to build x64 binaries) for some reason, but that has no ovious reason to be a problem.

Any hint on how to debug this?
A tool to check what could be wrong in the def or lib file maybe?
Or could the command line be misleading me and another lib file is the corrupt one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems visual c++ linker did not like some lines in the .def generated bu gfortran.
The fortran dll was linked with mkl_rt.lib, so the output .def had the symbols

> ```
> __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_mkl_rt @19 DATA
> __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR @20 DATA
> ```

I removed this with a custom build step, and the lib generated from the def file by lib.exe is not anymore considered corrupt by link.exe